# Clear fields from a form except 1 object (access VBA)

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form in Access and i try to make a button that clears the total form.
it works but not for 1 field because in the database that field has NOT NULL given to it.

this is my form: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7EOI.png

When i pres on the button [Leeg Velden] 
then this vba code will be running:

```
Private Sub btnLeegVelden_Click()
    Dim object As Object

    For Each object In Screen.ActiveForm
        If Name(object) = "ibvoorraad" Then
            Me.ibvoorraad.Value = "0"
        Else

            If TypeName(object) = "TextBox" Then object.Value = ""
        End If
    Next object

    btnArtikelToevoegen.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

How can i add some code that will clear all the field but in the field "Voorraad" it needs to set it to 0 instead of empty.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the `.Name` property of the object in your if statement rather than using the function `Name()`.

Try this instead:

```
Private Sub btnLeegVelden_Click()

    Dim object As Object

    For Each object In Screen.ActiveForm
        If object.Name = "ibvoorraad" Then
            Me.ibvoorraad.Value = "0"
        Else
            If TypeName(object) = "TextBox" Then object.Value = ""
        End If
    Next object

    btnArtikelToevoegen.Enabled = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do: reference as Controls:

```
    Dim ctl As Control
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If ctl.Name = "ibvoorraad" Then
            Me.ibvoorraad.Value = "0"
        Else
            If ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Then
                ctl = ""
            End If
        End If
    Next ctl

    btnArtikelToevoegen.Enabled = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I would set a default value for any controls that cannot be null then use the following code

```
Dim ctL As Access.Control
For Each ctL In Me.Controls
    If ctL.ControlType = acTextBox Then
        ctL= ctL.DefaultValue
    End If
Next
```